# IEnumerable vs List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Is this is a proper use of `IEnumerable` or shell I use `List`?
what do I need to put in `<PropertyInfo>`?

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNewsList<T>(int FID)
    {
        CatomWebNetDataContext pg = (CatomWebNetDataContext)db.GetDb();
        return (from nls in pg.NewsCat_ITEMs
                  join vi in pg.VIRTUAL_ITEMs on nls.NC_VI_ID equals vi.VI_ID
                  where vi.VI_VF_ID == FID
                  select new { nls, vi });


    }
```

or

```
 public List<PropertyInfo> GetPublic<T>(int FID)
    {
        CatomWebNetDataContext pg = (CatomWebNetDataContext)db.GetDb();
        var nl = (from nls in pg.NewsCat_ITEMs
                join vi in pg.VIRTUAL_ITEMs on nls.NC_VI_ID equals vi.VI_ID
                where vi.VI_VF_ID == FID
                select new { nls, vi });

        List<PropertyInfo> retList = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (var item in nl)
        {
             retList.Add(item);
        }


        return retList;
    }
```

Comment: About your updated question.. You do not need to prepare list like that, look at the example I gave you ;)

Comment: as an aside, your linq query looks funky.  The join shouldn't be necessary if your dbml has the relationship.  return db.GetDb().NewsCat_ITEMs.Where(x=>x.VIRTUAL_ITEMs.VI_VF_ID == FID).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is an instace of type, that implements IEnumerable. What it means? That if you want to return the `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` you have to create a list (or array etc.) of it and then return it.. From the outside of the method it will look like you are returning `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` but really it will be a `List<PropertyInfo>`.

About your query... You have to select object of type `PropertyInfo`, but right now you ae returning some anonymouse type. You should try it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNewsList<T>(int FID)
{
    CatomWebNetDataContext pg = (CatomWebNetDataContext)db.GetDb();
    var result from nls in pg.NewsCat_ITEMs
               join vi in pg.VIRTUAL_ITEMs on nls.NC_VI_ID equals vi.VI_ID
               where vi.VI_VF_ID == FID
               select new PropertyInfo { SomeMember = nls, SomeOtherMember = vi };

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: now i get 

The type or namespace name 'PropertyInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: public static IEnumerable<newsListItems> GetNewsList<T>(int FID)
        {
            CatomWebNetDataContext pg = (CatomWebNetDataContext)db.GetDb();
            var result = (from nls in pg.NewsCat_ITEMs
                    join vi in pg.VIRTUAL_ITEMs on nls.NC_VI_ID equals vi.VI_ID
                    where vi.VI_VF_ID == FID
                    select new newsListItems { tt = nls, tt2 = vi });
            
            return result.ToList();
            
        }

Comment: Are you sure that you have newsListItems class defined somewhere? Can you show me it's code?

Comment: no, i dont have a class "newsListItems". i thought that i could be a new type of object, do i need to create it? its a join table from my DB. there is another way to return the "result"?

Comment: No.. you cannot return anonymouse type in a method. You have to create a class that represents your entity (in this case got from joined tables).

Also why are you put <T> in definition of your method? You do not use it in it's body, so consider removing it ;)

Comment: return nls because it most likely contains IEnumerable<VIRTUAL_ITEM>

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do with the result. [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19e6zeyy.aspx) basically only supports iterating over the results contained in the collection. [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) is more specific, and allows you to:

- Find out how many items are in the collection without iterating through all of them
- Easily access an item in a specific position in the list
- Add or remove items from the list

among other things. If you don't need the extra functionality, I would return IEnumerable. The caller of your method can easily do what you did to add the items to a List.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to return a `List<PropertyInfo>`, given that it's an implementation of `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>`. The only thing will be that it will look like a plain old `IEnumerable` to the caller function once it returns.